# How do I maintain the selected value of form in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using a for loop to load selected values

```
<form action="" target="_self"  >
    <select onchange="change(this.value)">
    @for (var i = 0 ; i< Model.sites.Count; i++)
    {
        <option value="@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.sites[i])">@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.sites[i])</option>
    }
    </select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></noscript>
</form>
```

And submitting it via javascript call to my controller in which returns a model.

```
public ActionResult site_history_layout(string value)
    {
         var points= new points();
             points.grades = new List<string>();
        // etc.. code here 
    }
```

where value is the option value i get when onchange() is called.

Everything works, but how should I go about maintaining the value that I selected previously?  Since it resets with every form submission.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions !

I used ViewBag and even though this was unconventional way of using View, it works.

```
   @for (var i = 0 ; i< Model.sites.Count; i++)
    {
           if (i == ViewBag.site_selected)
            {
            <option selected value="@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.sites[i])">@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.sites[i])</option>
             }
               else
                {
                        <option  value="@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.sites[i])">@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.sites[i])</option>
                }
    }
```

I used an if statement and once it is the value i want it will insert the class "selected".

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to persist the previously selected values in some way. Consider using local storage or cookies. If security isn't an issue, just create a local storage object in the user's browser memory and then when the page loads, query to that to repopulate the selection(s).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 1):

So many options...

1. ViewData (or ViewBag or TempData): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option
2. Session state: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
3. jQuery AJAX and JS variable (instead of submitting a `form`): https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
4. HTML5 Local Storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: ...and simple value passing between pages via html forms :) depends on what he is trying to do

Comment: Right! Old school input type=hidden.